What is this tower in Bonn opposite Bundeshäuschen?
Can't find anything for this on the net.


Google Maps tells us it’s part of Haus Carstanjen and Wikipedia has more info.
The trees make it so you see just the tower, but there’s a whole building next to it.
Over the last few decades it has housed a variety of federal services (including the Treasury at one point) and services.
